# Problemas al Instalar Spotify

Tags: system-installation, appcenter, resolution, install, spotify

Intente instalar Spotify en mi laptop, sin exito, ahora resivo un anuncio muy molesto cada vez que abro mi centro de aplicaciones (adjunto imag[image]en)

Doy clic en detalles y obtengo lo siguiente:
W: Error de GPG: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
E: El repositorio «http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease» no está firmado.
W: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
W: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
E: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease is not (yet) available (The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45)

Por favor su apoyo para que no me salga este mensaje de error cada vez que entro al centro de apliaciones.

Apoyo para instalar spotify. mi sistema es elementary OS 5.1.4 Hera

Gracias

Comment: Welcome to elementary OS SE. Your participation is much appreciated. Please allow me to inform you that questions and answers posted of Stack Exchange should be in English. This doesn’t in any sense show any disrespect to any language rather for the well being of the community. Because if you post in English, people will be able to understand the situation properly and provide a better solution. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Remove Spotify sudo apt remove --purge spotify
Then install Spotify using a flatpak. There are plenty tutorials in the Google how to do this via flatpak.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The correct way to do it is to follow the official instructions for Debian/Ubuntu at...:
https://www.spotify.com/nl/download/linux/

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but in 2022, following the official page https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/.

The best way is:

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey_5E3C45D7B312C643.gpg | sudo apt-key add -

echo "deb http://repository.spotify.com stable non-free" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/spotify.list

sudo apt update

sudo apt install spotify-client
```

[image]

Works fine!